# Language Worker Process exited. Pid=18612 Azure Function error

Tags: c#, azure, function, process, azure-functions

I've been trying to run azure function locally with multiple projects on my laptop , but whenever I start the project on the visual studio it gives this error

```
[2023-04-26T12:22:15.095Z] Language Worker Process exited. Pid=18612.
[2023-04-26T12:22:15.098Z] C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe exited with code -2147450730 (0x80008096). https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed.
[2023-04-26T12:22:15.168Z] https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed
[2023-04-26T12:22:15.170Z] Language Worker Process exited. Pid=3944.
[2023-04-26T12:22:15.173Z] C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe exited with code -2147450730 (0x80008096). https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed.
[2023-04-26T12:22:15.348Z] Failed to start a new language worker for runtime: dotnet-isolated.
[2023-04-26T12:22:15.351Z] System.Private.CoreLib: A task was canceled.612"
```

I've already tried to update the Nu-Get Packages but still this issue is occuring.

Packages installed:
*Dot-Net version:7.0.202*
*.NET SDKs installed:
7.0.202 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
.NET runtimes installed:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.30 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.30 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.32 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.15 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 7.0.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.30 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.32 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.15 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.32 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.15 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 7.0.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]*

Comment: Hey @Hamza, What NuGet Packages you're updating and What function app you're checking/using - Function App version along with .NET Core/Framework and its version? And You're saying that your solution contains multiple projects. Are all the projects belongs to same Stack and version or different?

Answer (score 0):

> Language Worker Process exited. Pid=3944.
> C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe exited with code -2147450730 (0x80008096).  Failed to start a new language worker for runtime: dotnet-isolated.
> System.Private.CoreLib: A task was canceled.612

The worker process is unable to start due to a missing or incorrect configuration or issues with the .NET runtime or SDK.

Check if the below steps helps you to fix the issue:

1. Check that you have the correct version of the .NET runtime installed. You can check in [Registry Editor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed#detect-net-framework-45-and-later-versions). Update your .NET SDK to the latest version which resolves compatibility issues.

[image]

2. Ensure that your project is configured correctly to use the .NET isolated worker process.

Latest .NET Core or .NET Framework versions which can be used with specific Function runtime versions as shown in [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide#supported-versions):

[image]

3. Check that your project references are correct and that all required packages are installed and up to date.
4. Restart Visual Studio, clean and rebuild your project and run it again.
5. Check if you have `dotnet-isolated` application setting in `local.settings.json` .

[image]

Comment: check the comment please